# Teacher-Student App; Communication between mobile devices

Tags: ios, mobile, client-server, communication

A client asked me to write an app(iOS) for him, in where the teacher does something on his tablet and the students see something happening in realtime on their mobile devices. 
Example:
Teacher asks a question; students see the question and answer it; teacher sees who clicked what

Now, what is the best way to approach that technologically?
I have thought of these ways so far:

- Setup a server and do the communication over the server -> Problem: the client devices would need some kind of push notification system
- register all the client devices to the teacher device and then communicate directly with them

Neither of these ways does sound nice to me. Does anyone of you have experience with this kind of use case? Is there maybe a another easier alternative to do it? Is there some kind of RMI for iOS?

Many thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: It looks like [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/) may be available for iOS later this year.  It's currently available for Android and other platforms.  Could be too late for your timeline, though...

Comment: if ipad to ipad screen share is possible like iPad to MAC (Reflection app)

Comment: reflection would not be enough. the teacher sets up questions and the students have to answer - I wasn't very clear in the question

Answer (score 1):

ios and android have built in push notification systems

i would suggest to use some kind of web service for your server (like REST)

also you might not need the push notifications.  If the clients are connected to the server then they can receive data via that connection.